# Copying or moving a file inside Internal storage on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, internal-storage

In an Android app the user can record his voice. The sound recording is saved in a file defined by:

```
audioTempFile = File(getFilesDir(), "Audio_Temp_File")
```

Then I want to give the user the choice of the final folder and file name for the file to be saved.
So the audioTempFile above can be used for a possible next recording without destroying the current one.

For example let us assume I want the file to be saved in this file called finalFile :

```
val rootDir = getFilesDir()
val storeDir = File(rootDir, "MyStorageDirectory")
val finalFile = File(storeDir, "MyFinalFileName")
```

How can I move or possibly copy *audioTempFile* to *finalFile*?

I did not find any clear answer by searching the net.

Comment: There is a function File.renameTo() for that.

Comment: `val rootDir = getFilesDir()` ? val filesDir = getFilesDir()

Comment: val finalFile = File(getFilesDir(), "folder/file.mp3")

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about saving to a specific location, but this is the way I'm saving the recordings in my app.

```kotlin
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q){
                        try{
                            val values = ContentValues()
                            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, allFiles[position].name)
                            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3")
                            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC)
                            val savedAudio = context.contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)
                            val outputStream = savedAudio?.let {
                                context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(it)
                            }
                            val fis = FileInputStream(allFiles[position])
                            var length : Int
                            val buffer = ByteArray(8192)
                            while (fis.read(buffer).also { length = it } > 0) {
                                outputStream?.write(buffer, 0,length)
                            }
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Audio Saved to Music Folder", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }catch (e : IOException){
                        Toast.makeText(
                            context,
                            "There was an error saving the file",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                    }else{
                        try {
                            val audioDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC)
                            val audio = File(audioDir, allFiles[position].name)
                            val fis = FileInputStream(allFiles[position])
                            val fos = FileOutputStream(audio)
                            var length : Int
                            val buffer = ByteArray(8192)
                            while (fis.read(buffer).also { length = it } > 0){
                                fos.write(buffer,0,length)
                            }
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Audio Saved to Music Folder", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }catch (e : IOException){
                            Toast.makeText(
                                context,
                                "There was an error saving the file",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            ).show()
                            e.printStackTrace()
                        }
                    }
```

You would need `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission if u want to save files other than public directories. It's recommended to use MediaStore API to save your files.

Do correct me if I'm wrong as I'm still learning.

Hope this helps u :)

Comment: As you can read in my post, I am already saving the recorded audio in audioTempFile. The question is about moving or copying a file.

Comment: And I am not trying to save in external storage.

Comment: I am saving the file in temp folder as well, this method is just copying the file from the temp folder and writing it in the public `Music` Folder.

Comment: @M_Ashhal. I see, sorry I was a bit quick to read your answer. So you are doing it the hard way (basically to the copy "by hand"). I may have to do that also, I was hoping thee would be a convenient API function to move a file or to copy it.

Comment: I don't know what u mean by the hard way, cause this is the only way it worked for me without the ScopedStorage Permission. MediaStore is the recommended to store audio now. You can read more here -> https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage

Comment: `It's recommended to use MediaStore API to save your files.` Well you can as well use the other code on Q+. No need for mediastore at all.

Comment: `ScopedStorage Permission.` ? Never heard of. What do you mean?

Comment: `am already saving the recorded audio in audioTempFile` ? Again your own description @Michel. No you are saving your recording in getFilesDir().

Comment: @blackapps Which other code can be used? Can u tell me so I can improve my code

Comment: @blackapps by scopedStorage, I meant `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission as I had already mentioned it above, didn't want to type it again.

Comment: Well it would be a 'Not Scoped Storage' permission then. And if you dont like to type long words again and again then use 'all files permission' as that is where it is known by.

Comment: Ok, then other than all files permission, which methods can be used to store into public storage directory as this was the only method working for me

Comment: The other code is your own code for below Q. Just dont use mediastore. Not needed.